# redirect adding %20HTTP to end of the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im redirecting this:

`example.com/category/name-of-title/number`

to this:

`example.com/name-of-title/number`

Everything is working perfect except its adding `%20HTTP` to the end of the url after the redirect like so:

`example.com/name-of-title/number%20HTTP`

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category/(.*)/(.*) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: patterns like `.*` eats everything so it may be buggy. Try more specific one like this `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category/([^/\ ]+)/ [NC]` (the second subpattern is not needed there).

Answer (score 0):

Because [as the documentation states](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), `THE_REQUEST` is

> *“[t]he full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1")”*

– so in your case, that would be something like `GET /category/name-of-title/number HTTP/1.1`, and applying the pattern `/category/(.*)/(.*)` onto that results in exactly the part `name-of-title/number HTTP` as the first match (and the remaining `1.1` as the second), because of the greediness of regular expressions.

It is nonsense anyway to use a `RewriteCond` and the value `THE_REQUEST` for this – a simple `RewriteRule` like this should work perfectly fine:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

And if you want to match *anything* that could be behind `category/` anyway, you don’t even need two capturing subpatterns, but could simply use

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i tried the above code and it does not work. This is how i had it originally.

Comment: @user1904598: Test this rule in a new browser.

Comment: tested in new browser. the URL does not redirect. It only works with the my original code but adds the %20HTTP. Hmm.. So strange cause i can get other URL to redirect just this one giving me a problem.

Comment: i tired this:   `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category/([^/\ ]+)/ [NC]` 

`RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]` and it worked but left the number off the end of the url. only gave me `example.com/name-of-title/`

Answer (score 0):

`%20http` is an empty space!

Remove the space, and this `%20http` will no longer appear.